# Inheritance and polymorphism - understanding

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class A and class B which extends A and is a subclass. Now i have

```
A aObject = new A(); and
A bObject = new B();
```

Now can i call the method in class B which is not in A using bObject without typecasting ?

If we cant do so without typecasting, what is the advantage of polymorphism then?

Thanks.

Comment: What situation are you in where you find yourself needing to invoke methods specific to B even though you hold a reference via A? Are you just trying to learn or do you really need that functionality for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.  On both objects `aObject` and `bObject` you can call only methods that are defined for `A` without using casting.

If you defined `bObject` to be of type `B`, then you could, but as your code stands you can only work with `A`'s methods and members.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram Thanks. in such a case what is the advantage of polymorphism ?

Comment: @ynwa, a comment isn't sufficient space to talk about the advantages of polymorphism. But generally speaking, try to think that for any functionality defined on a super class (via its API), you can further specialize or override that behavior on subclasses. Adding to the API is going beyond that. Simplistic example. Animals make noises. However, cats meow. Dogs bark. If you have `void speak()` defined in your animal superclass, you can create the specific correct behaviors in your subclasses.

Comment: so from my understanding, if a superclass method was overrided by subclass, then the method calling will be on the basis of the instance present in the object ? Like if A has speak() method and B overrides speak(). A bObject = new B(); bObject.speak() will call overrided method and A aObject = new A(); aObject.speak() will call method in A. Am i right ?

Comment: @ynwa, in your example, you haven't used  your classes polymorphically, but I *think* you have the caught onto the right idea. Consider `Animal a = new Cat(); Animal b = new Dog(); a.speak(); b.speak();`. Both variables are of type Animal, the actual objects are subclasses. If those subclasses have overriden `speak()`, you will get their more specialized behaviors. The cat will meow, and the dog will bark.

Comment: @ Anthony Pengram Thanks. So if i have something like Animal a = new Dog(); i can call only the methods in Animal class and the overridden methods in Dog class. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to call the methods defined on Animal. If you have overriden them in Dog, then you will observe those behaviors. Via `Animal a`, the dog should be able to speak, eat, go to sleep. You will not be able to directly instruct the dog to wag its tail.

Answer (score 3):

No, you definitely need to cast bObject to B.

This is because, as far as the compiler is concerned, bObject is of the declared class A. Imagine that instead of using a constructor, you had returned bObject from a function which returns class A..... how could the compiler possibly know that it is actually of class B?

You therefore need to do a *runtime* cast or instanceof check before the compiler will let you use it as class B.

Comment: Even after an `instanceof` check you would need to do a cast if you wanted to get to one of `B`'s members.

Comment: So typecasting is the only way ? Is it a good programming practice ?

Answer (score 2):

No, both aObject and bObject are now of type A now.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The only way to avoid the cast is if you were willing to do:

```
B bObject = new B();
```

That's because the *declared type* of an object (the type to the left of the variable declaration) determines what methods can be invoked, and if you write that the type is `A`, then only methods from `A` can be called ... unless you do a cast.

Answer (score 1):

i will use the example that i used to learn so that you understand polymorphism:

you are creating a game consisting of several animals. One important aspect of this animals is how they move.
then you define a class:

```
class Animal{
 void move(){}
}
```

but do frogs and mammals move them same way? no they don't. Again, you are not in a position to know which animal currently is being manipulated since the type of animal being created is done randomly (so i guess, for the benefit of the game). then what you have is a reference to animal, you can get the type yes (reflection) but why the hustle? 
so you subclass animal class for all the possible type of animals and override their move behaviour.

```
class Frog extends Animal{
 void move(){ hop();}
}

class Snake extends Animal{
 void move(){crawl();}
}
```

now you have your animal manager somewhere that randomly generates types of animals:

```
static Animal createAnimal(){
Animal a = null;
//generate a randomly
return a;
}
```

now you can say

```
Animal a = AnimalManager.createAnimal();
a.move(); //it may hop or crawl. it just does not matter how it does it. you dont care whether it is a Frog, a Snake, a Man. but it will move. now thats polymorphism!
```